# Saving top output to txt file in python is adding strange characters to file

Tags: python, txt

I have a python program that saves the top output to a text file, the snippet is as follows:

```
import subprocess
adb_shell = 'adb shell'

file_to_write = open(file_name, 'w')

for i in range (1,number_of_samples):
    subprocess.call(adb_shell+ ' "top -m 10 -n 1; echo "----------" ', stdout=file_to_write)
    time.sleep(5)

file_to_write.close()
```

The capture works fine, that is, the program saves the output of top -m 10 -n 1, basically top 10 threads, every 5 seconds or so.

The problem is that when I open the text file (no matter which text editor), I see some funky characters that were added.

The file opened in Notepad:

[image: This is the notepad output]

The file opened with Notepad++

[image: This is the Notepad++ output]

The main issue is that when I post-process the txt file sometimes I need to do manual cleanup because my script ignores big chunks of the file because of these extra characters.

Full disclaimer, this seems to be related to newer versions of Android, I believe post 8. In older version, the same script produced a clean text file without anything extra added to it.

Also, if I run the top command in a cmd window, i do not see anything strange, so it has to be the way I am saving the text file.

Tips are appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be commands for the terminal (e. g. setting color). Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409053/how-to-disable-color-in-output-of-top-command

Comment: Yup, adding "-bn1" to the top command got rid of anything strange.